# errors while using pip install on windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 lts

Tags: python, windows, pip, pycharm

I'm not new with Python programming, today I tried to install Django using "pip install Django" on my computer.
I'm using Python 3.9.1, pip 20.2.3, PyCharm (community) 2020.3.2 .
I've tried everything, using pip3, trying to install libraries from pycharm termianl and from the pycharm interpreter configuration, I even format my computer(full foramt and the quick foramt) and nothing helped my.
I searched for similar problems here but all of them didn't work.
I get this problem over and over again (I tried to set the timeout to 100, and my internet connection is good and fast enough):  (in this tryout I've tried to install numpy library, I get the same problem with every library that I tried)

(venv) C:\Users\achik\PycharmProjects\first>pip install numpy
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/numpy/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/numpy/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/numpy/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/numpy/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnection
Pool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/numpy/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for numpy

Please help me, I'm about to lose my mind

UPDATE:
I formatted my computer and reinstall windows 10, installed python
3.7 and older version of PyCharm and it didn't work.
I formatted again my pc and installed Ubuntu 18.04 lts and again I have the same problem.
PLEASE help me!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Sometimes it is because of internet connection and sometimes cmd working so slow.
If your antifilter is open, close it before executing commands on cmd.
And whenever you faced this problem close cmd and run it as admin again...
you can install needed packages without using pip as well.
For example download a suitable version of numpy and save it on C:\Python\Tools\script and run it using cmd.

Comment: hey, thanks for you comment.   what is anti-filter an how do I closing it?       I tried to open the cmd as a admin

Comment: I mean if you are using VPN close the VPN and try again.

Answer (score 0):

In Pycharm sometime this type of issue happens due to their venv file, if possible then please remove venv file from pycharm directory any add python in the environment variable
and try to install NumPy from CMD.
I hope this will resolve your issue, I was also facing the same issue and tried this & fortunately being solved.

Comment: Python is in the environment settings (this is happens by default when you install pycharm after 2019), I made sure that it is there manually, I tried to install any library using the CMD and the GIT bash , nothing helped!!!

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error while installing django using pip. I solved it by disabling the cache

```
pip --no-cache-dir install <package name>
```